# How can I add extra TableRows to my TableLayout depending on cursor?

Tags: android, cursor, tablelayout

I have a database with different results in my database in my Android project. I want to fetch these results and show them in a tablelayout. In the tablelayout I want to add a row for each result, and write the column "date" on one textview, and the "result" on the second textview. Both textviews are on the same row. I fetch the data and store it in a cursor.

My question is: How do I use the cursor and add a row depending on how much data there is in my database?

Right now I try to add a row for each row in the cursor like this:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_layout2);
     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
     tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             TextView mTvDate = new TextView(this);
             TextView mTvResult = new TextView(this);
             int x=0;
             for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
             mTvDate.setText(date[x]);
             mTvResult.setText(""+nocorrect[x]+" av "+ noqs[x] +" ("+ proc[x]+ "%)");
             mTvDate.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

             mTvResult.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             tr.addView(mTvDate);
             tr.addView(mTvResult);
     tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             }
```

But I think I need to create a NEW tablerow, cause I get this error message:

```
02-22 09:22:17.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

But I don't want to remove it, I want to add more. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try this
i think you adding same row every time. so just declare it every loop iteration.

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_layout2);

         int x=0;
         for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
 tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         TextView mTvDate = new TextView(this);
         TextView mTvResult = new TextView(this);
         mTvDate.setText(date[x]);
         mTvResult.setText(""+nocorrect[x]+" av "+ noqs[x] +" ("+ proc[x]+ "%)");
         mTvDate.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

         mTvResult.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(mTvDate);
         tr.addView(mTvResult);
 tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         }
```

Comment: Hi! Perfect. How annoying I couldn't figure that out.Thanks!